# How to handle Timezone offset with daylight savings?

Tags: javascript, php, date

In my website user A creates an event that starts at 9:00am. I convert that time to GMT so that it if User B in a different timezone two hours ahead see's that event it can be converted to the time zone of User B and show that the event starts at 11:00am.

My problem is that if user A creates an event during daylight savings then views it when daylight savings is over the timezone offset will be off by one hour. This results in the event starting at 8:00am when it is not daylight savings and 9:00am when it is daylight savings. Any recommendations on how to fix this with javascript or php?

My only thought is when I get the timezone offset like below should I always set the date to january so that I always get the same timezone offset regardless of the actual month? Or is there a better way to deal with this?

```
d = new Date();
d.setMonth(1);
d.getTimezoneOffset()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking?  You should always add the timezone offset *at the time in question*.  If you do that, there won't be any off-by-1-hour errors.

Comment: @MarkReed Do you mean when creating the event storing the timezone offset with the event and using that value when converting it to different timezones?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?  If I create an event that takes place in May at 9AM EDT, that gets stored as 1300 UTC.  If I look at that May event when it's currently December, it's still going to show up as 9AM, because the time zone offset for May is 4 hours, even though the current one in December is 5.

Comment: Now, if you're trying to schedule *recurring* events, so that meeting in May is  still happening every week or whatever when we get to December, then yes, you have to store the local time and time offset instead of just storing UTC.

Comment: @MarkReed Yes I was trying to do recurring events and your solution fixed it so thank you. When using `new Date().getTimezoneOffset()` I now do `new Date(eventDate).getTimezoneOffset()` so that the offset is always the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The time zone offset returned by `getTimezoneOffset` is *for the date the method is being called on*, not for the current time.  So just always ask for the time zone of the event you're displaying and you should be fine.

However, note that if you're scheduling a *recurring* event, the time needs to be stored and handled as local time instead of universal.  Otherwise the meeting time will jump by an hour whenever Daylight Saving Time starts or ends.